# Can cloudfront support websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websocket, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have my website Angular based hosted in AWS S3 bucket fronted by cloud front for SSL and caching etc.My URL's and route 53 entries point to CloudFront.
If I have to invoke a websocket [may be imagine its a publicly accessible websocket], wont it work ; i read cloud front doesn't support WebSockets?

I am invoking websockets from S3;Cloudfront is just infront of it.Does that help or this wont work at all?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018-11, CloudFront now supports WebSocket:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudfront-announces-support-for-the-websocket-protocol/

Answer (score 1):

Amazon CloudFront doesn't support WebSockets at the moment so you cannot proxy WebSocket connections through CloudFront.

If you have EC2 instances running in your backend, use the Application Load Balancer which also allows adding AWS Issued SSL certificates and connect through WebSockets.

Comment: Can my S3 code invoke some websocket?Does that a work? Can it work as a socket client atleast?

Comment: When you say S3 code, I assume its the JS code loaded to browser right? If so you should be able to listen to Websockets from the browser

Answer (score 0):

The Protocol upgrade should be from the Origin, in your case if your Origin is doing that, CloudFront should work with websocket.